# Specify type for arbitrary data types

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python `3.6.6`:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
df_test_cor_cols: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame = df_test[selected_cols]
```

The problem is that on the last line I get:

> NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined

So, is there a way in Python `3.6.6`(or any other version) to specify the type for arbitrary data types such `panda`?

Comment: Because you imported it `as pd`...

Comment: You imported `pandas as pd`. So use `pd` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import panda as pd
```

In your main namespace, pd now represents panda. So instead of:

```
df_test_cor_cols: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame = df_test[selected_cols]
```

Try:

```
df_test_cor_cols: pd.core.frame.DataFrame = df_test[selected_cols]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `pandas` with `pd`.

```
import pandas as pd          #you've imported `pandas` as `pd`
```